# Files needed to deploy to another tier when updating service reference in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, console-application, webservice-client

I have multiple projects in my solution, one of them makes the call to a web service, since the contract has changed I made the 'Update Web Reference' from the client. After that I re-build the project and I see the dll (and the others from the other projects) in my bin-Debug folder. Is that dll the only file that I should place in the QA server where the client is hosted? Is the wsdl (and other needed items) embedded in this file? I'm new using web services so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct . When you update the web reference what happens is based on the wsdl a proxy class is created which gets compiled to the dll you are seeing . You don't need to deploy wsdl for deployment .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, good to know it.